# Why no fizzbuzz being printed out?

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

This is my code. I am not getting any Fizz buzz printed. I am only getting numbers. Could anyone explain why? Thanks

```
printOut = ""; 

for (var x=1; x < 101 ; x++) {


  switch(x) {

      case((x%3) == 0):
      printOut+="\n"+ "Fizz" ;
      break;

      case((x%5) == 0):
      printOut+="\nBuzz";
      break;

      default:
      printOut+="\n" + x ;
      break;

  }

}
console.log(printOut);
```

Comment: That is not the correct syntax of `switch/case`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: To be specific, `case` only accepts values to compare against the expression in the `switch` clause. You cannot dynamically evaluate the `case`'s value like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `switch` statement improperly. Each `case (value):` is basically supposed to be run whenever `x` equals `value`.

To solve this problem, simply remove the `switch` statement entirely, and substitute `if`s for each `case`:

```
for (var x = 1; x < 101; x++) {
    if ((x % 3) == 0)
        printOut += "\n" + "Fizz";
    else if ((x % 5) == 0)
        printOut += "\nBuzz";
    else
        printOut += "\n" + x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

check how you're using the switch statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

in the switch line x is your expression and ((x%5) == 0) is your value.  I think what you mean to do is a handful of if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match the value of `x` with expressions whose values are either `true` or `false`. You can pass true in the switch and the switch will "match" with the first case statement that evaluates as true.

While this sort-a works, I would recommend just doing if/else statements. This won't work for number 30 which is both True for X%3 and x%5. It will match with the x%3 first and stop there.

```
printOut = ""; 

for (var x=1; x < 101 ; x++) {


  switch(true) {

      case((x%3) == 0):
      printOut+="\n"+ "Fizz" ;
      break;

      case((x%5) == 0):
      printOut+="\nBuzz";
      break;

      default:
      printOut+="\n" + x ;
      break;

  }

                             }
console.log(printOut);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!